# Map class - use case

Tags: c++, string

I'm reading [this](https://github.com/thunlp/NRE/blob/master/CNN%2BATT/init.h) C++ code. At line 58 is defined a variable of type `map<string,int>`. Then, at line 109, the author writes `relationMapping[(string)(buffer)]=id` where `buffer` is a char list (cf line 104) and `id` is an int variable. I don't understand the syntax `(string)(buffer)`. I suppose the author wants to convert `buffer` to a string. I know that this can be done using  `(string) buffer`. Is `(string)(buffer)` equivalent to `(string) buffer` ?

Comment: Yes. For any variable `x`, `(x)` and `x` are equal and is commutative. But you don't need the cast anyway, if `buffer` is a type that the `std::string` constructor accepts as a valid string (like another `std::string`, or a `char*`, or an array of `char`).

Comment: That's some pretty bad code to be honest - it's mixing C and C++ in weird ways (e.g. using `malloc` and `free`)